# In order tree traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given a binary tree traversal program, how would I modify the traverse function below to have std::string as its return type and print the name of each node on the same line?

```
void traverse(Node* head){
    if(head == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    traverse(head->left);       //Visit left subtree
    std::cout << head->name;
    traverse(head->right);      // Visit right subtree   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```cpp
std::string traverse(Node* head){
    if(head == nullptr) {
        return "";
    }
    std::string s = traverse(head->left);       // Visit left subtree
    s += head->name + " ";
    s += traverse(head->right);                 // Visit right subtree
    return s;
}
```

but if your tree is a bamboo:

```
       a  <- root
      / \
nullptr  b
        / \
 nullptr  ...
            \
             z
            / \
     nullptr   nullptr
```

complexity of the code above will be `O(n^2)`, because right subtree string is always copied and there are no easy and graceful ways to escape this.

So it's better not to return string, but pass reference to a string:

```cpp
void traverse(Node* head, std::string& s){
    if(head == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    traverse(head->left, s);       // Visit left subtree
    s += head->name + " ";
    traverse(head->right, s);      // Visit right subtree
}
```

Comment: It's not very useful here but you can get `O(n log n)` by always copying the smaller subtree.

Comment: @BessieTheCow yep, but key problem here that the must save order of strings, anyway right is appened to the left, so right's space will be reallocated in the left one, that trick as I understood won't work here.

Comment: Oh right I forgot about that. I guess *technically* you can use `std::deque<char>`...